# How to install a war file into JbossFuse?

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I have a project that generates some war files. Right now I'm trying to install it into jbossfuse before creating a container to it.

So into fuse I've done that:

```
features:install war
```

I'm using a virtual machine with CentOS7 and jbossfuse, so I copied my war file into // and then I run this to install the war:

```
JBossFuse:admin@root> install war:file://my_project.war
```

When I run this I get this:

```
Bundle IDs: 
Error executing command: Error installing bundles:
    Unable to install bundle war:file://my_project.war
```

Basically I've followed the steps here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Deploying_into_the_Container/files/DeployWar-Convert.html

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Could you please check for exceptions in fuse.log?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is accessible it should work , can you please post the whole stack trace